# How do I separate a 2 digit number into individual digits?

Tags: c++, integer, digit

The program prompts the user to enter a 2 digit decimal number. How do I separate the number into two separate variables after the user enters it?

Later I need to use the first and the second part of the number so they need to be in different variables.

Comment: Sorry, forgot in C++.

Comment: I've added the tag for you (and removed a couple of non-meaningful others). In the future, please add the language as a tag so your question is clear, and so that the search feature can find it for future readers searching for help in that tag. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Start by dividing the number by ten, there you have the first number.

```
int i = 99;
int oneNumber = i / 10;
```

You really should try to get the next one by yourself.

Comment: Thanks this worked, Didn't realise you can use modules to do that, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

```
void split(int input, int& first, int& second) {
   first = input / 10;
   second = input % 10;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first read them into `char cNum[3]` (last one is `'\0'`), then

```
int firstNumber = cNum[0]-'0';
int secondNumber = cNum[1]-'0';
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a character string you can split it in two strings and use atoi() on both...

```
char s[2];
s[1] = 0;
s[0] = yourstring[0];
int i1 = atoi(s);
s[0] = yourstring[1];
int i2 = atoi(s);
```

This is of course quick and dirty and does not include any error checking.
It will return 0 for invalid characters though...